# Can I use the iOS system icon in my app?

Tags: cocoa

I want to create a button with the icon like UIBarButtonSystemItemAction  style, how can I use the icon of the UIBarButtonItem icons,
what is the name of it? Or is there some system URL is for it?

Comment: https://github.com/pixelfreak/iOS-UI-Assets

Comment: It`s so good ,thanks a lot